# EF core 3 problem by string to npgsqlTime

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Hey guys im using Npgsql  and need to pass parameters to my PostgreSQL stored procedure
my stored procedure expecting Date for my first two parameters:

```
SELECT wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(
<date>,
<date>,
<character varying>,
<character varying>,
<character varying>
```

);

so i need to pass date parameters :

```
        NpgsqlDateTime DateFrom = NpgsqlDateTime.Parse(dtFrom);
        NpgsqlDateTime DateTo = NpgsqlDateTime.Parse(dtTo);
        NpgsqlParameter p0 = new NpgsqlParameter("@drfrom", dtFrom);
        NpgsqlParameter p1 = new NpgsqlParameter("@dtto",dtTo);
        NpgsqlParameter p2 = new NpgsqlParameter("@regionalmanager", regionalManager);
        NpgsqlParameter p3 = new NpgsqlParameter("@serviceunder", service_under);
        NpgsqlParameter p4 = new NpgsqlParameter("@supervisor", supervisor);
    
        var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(@drfrom,@dtto,@regionalmanager,@serviceunder,@supervisor)
                            res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)",p0,p1,p2,p3,p4
                          ).ToList();
```

dtfrom and dtto are string date format which is:

```
dtFrom="2020/07/03"
dtTo="2020/07/07"
```

but it gives me an error on the line

```
NpgsqlDateTime DateFrom = NpgsqlDateTime.Parse(dtFrom);
```

that the format is not correct!any help?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @viveknuna cant parse the string ,the error is System.FormatException: 'One of the identified items was in an invalid format.'

Comment: try `DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.Parse(dtFrom);`

Comment: @viveknuna then i get Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: function wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, text, text, text) does not exist'
 because of the diffrent formats

Comment: check the query, its wrong

Comment: @viveknuna give me a hint which part is wrong please?two days  is lost for this :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source:

[NpgsqlDateTime](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/9008d56eb6275d44b6e2aee41e9f268e2cf4cae4/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlTypes/NpgsqlDateTime.cs/#L212)

which calls [NpgsqlDate](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/9008d56eb6275d44b6e2aee41e9f268e2cf4cae4/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlTypes/NpgsqlDate.cs/#L102)
along with `Timespan.Parse()` which seems mandatory.

Since you are not using a time, you could use `NpgsqlDate.Parse()` instead.

The source seems to be expecting the following format for date parsing: yyyy-MM-dd

So if you meant the 3rd of July

```
dtFrom="2020-07-03"
```

but if you meant the 7th of March

```
dtFrom="2020-03-07"
```

Source code:

```
try {
    var idx = str.IndexOf('-');
    if (idx == -1) {
        throw new FormatException();
    }
    var year = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, idx));
    var idxLast = idx + 1;
    if ((idx = str.IndexOf('-', idxLast)) == -1) {
        throw new FormatException();
    }
    var month = int.Parse(str.Substring(idxLast, idx - idxLast));
    idxLast = idx + 1;
    if ((idx = str.IndexOf(' ', idxLast)) == -1) {
        idx = str.Length;
    }
    var day = int.Parse(str.Substring(idxLast, idx - idxLast));
    if (str.Contains("BC")) {
        year = -year;
    }
    return new NpgsqlDate(year, month, day);
} catch (OverflowException) {
    throw;
} catch (Exception) {
    throw new FormatException();
}
```

Additionally if `NpgsqlDate.Parse` is not accepted, you could use NpgsqlDateTime.Parse with the time part set to zero.

```
NpgsqlDateTime.Parse("2020-07-03 00:00")
```

Comment: if i use "2020-07-03" formart i still get the same error One of the identified items was in an invalid forma,its very strange

Comment: @ilmagnifico I took a look at the source again and it expects a time when using the datetime parser. Use the date type instead.

Comment: it converts it!your dilution works but the stupidest thing is when i want to pass it as a parameter to my store procedure it says No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'NpgsqlDate

Comment: @ilmagnifico I added an example for `NpgsqlDateTime`.